# Setting the window shape in Java (shaped JFrame)

Tags: java, user-interface, awt, illegalargumentexception

I'm trying to set the shape of my JFrame window to an ellipse, but instead it is throwing the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at Splash.setShape(Splash.java:48)
    at Splash.<init>(Splash.java:25)
    at BackOffice.init(BackOffice.java:40)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The problem is that I am sending 2 parameters and the method only accepts 2 parameters so I can't see where I am getting this error from? The line that the error points to is the line which says `mSetWindowShape.invoke(this, shape);` here is the relevant method:

```
private void setShape() {
    Class<?> awtUtilitiesClass;
    try {
        awtUtilitiesClass = Class.forName("com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities");
        Method mSetWindowShape = awtUtilitiesClass.getMethod("setWindowShape", Window.class, Shape.class);
        Shape shape = (Shape) new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        mSetWindowShape.invoke(this, shape);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

**EDIT:** I took off one paramter and got the same error (wrong number of arguments). I then put in 3 parameters (window, shape, 0) and got 'argument type mismatch'. I then tried a boolean and a string as the third parameter but those gave the 'argument type mismatch' too. I don't understand this because in the tutorial it only shows 2 parameters. Now apparently there are three?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your:

```
mSetWindowShape.invoke(this, shape);
```

should be:

```
mSetWindowShape.invoke(null, this, shape);
```

The [Method.invoke()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29) method takes the object the method is being invoked on as the first argument.  Since AWTUtilities.setWindowShape() is a static method, the first argument should be null.

Also, if you can target Java 7, use [Frame.setShape()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setShape%28java.awt.Shape%29) instead as it is now officially part of the API.  It is possible for com.sun.* classes to go away in the future.

Comment: Wow head-ache over. Thanks a bunch!!

Answer (score 1):

I hope, this is the right method your code be calling for `frameObject.setShape(shape);`
Hope that helps. Regards.

Comment: this is probably correct for Java 1.7+ (as mentioned in the other answer) but i'm still on 1.6.